# Measure how spread out the data in an array is

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have an array of zeros and ones and I need to know if the data is spread out across the columns or concentrated in clumps.

For example:

If I have array `x` and it has these values:

Column 1 values: 1  1 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0   1 1 1 1

Column 2 values: 1  0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0 0 1 0  0 1   0 0 0 1

if we counted the number of ones we can know that it is the same number but the ones are more well spread out and distributed in column 2 compared with column 1.

I am trying to make a score that gives me a high value if the spreading is good and low value if the spreading is bad... any ideas??

Sample of Data:

```
1 0 0 0 5 0 -2 -3  0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0 0 1
2 0 0 0 0 0  0  3 -3 1 0
1 2 3 0 5 0  2 13  4 5 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 -4 34  0 0 1
```

Comment: I suspect that [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) measures this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to measure is the variance of the distribution of the number of `0`s between the `1`s, i.e:

```
f = @(x)std(diff(find(x)))
```

So for you data:

```
a = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
b = [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]

f(a)
    = 8.0498

f(b)
    = 2.0736
```

But I still think you're essentially trying to measure the disorder of the system which is what I imagine entropy measures but I don't know how

Note that this gives a *low* value if the "spreading" is good and a high value if it is bad (i.e. the opposite of your request).

Also if you want it per column then it becomes a little more complicated:

```
f = @(x)arrayfun(@(y)std(diff(find(x(:,y)))), 1:size(x,2))
data = [a', b'];
f(data)
```

**WARNING:** This method pretty much does not consider trailing and leading `0`s. I don't know if that's a problem or not. but basically `f([0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0])` returns `0` where as `f([1; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0])` returns a positive indicating (incorrectly) that first case is more distributed. One possible fix might be to prepend and append a row of ones to the matrix...

Comment: Think this makes more sense!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `x` is one array? You should define `x` as I have defined `a` or `b` above. Or else if `x` has multiple columns as your questions indicates (but it unclear on) then you must use the second form of `f` that uses `arrayfun`

Comment: Sorry u edited the question and I didn't see the new part. Thanks Dan it works very good but I am wondering if x is a matrix and I don't have a and b as x has many columns inside it, how can I make it work?

Comment: yes if `x` is in a format like `[1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0; 1, 1, 0; 1, 1, 1]` (i.e. each *column* is a binary vector that you are trying to score) it will still work

Comment: @Dan it didn't give me any number .. x is a matrix of size 1000X64, it just put the same equation in a variable also I think there is a missing bracket in f

Comment: @User436823 there was a missing bracket you're right. I've edited it. Please a a proper (subsample) of your `x`, say 10-by-5 or something, that we can copy and paste straight into Matlab so we know your exact format. Edit your question to add this

Comment: Ok, I will do that .. and will it work for normal values? not only ones? as I found some normal values in my data

Comment: @User436823 well it depends on what you're trying to measure. It will still work but it just considers all non zero numbers to be `1`s. This might be correct for you, it might not. It's impossible for us to say without knowing the full context of your project

Comment: I added a Sample of the data, 
if x is the matrix which I added, and I write f = @(x)array(@(y)std(diff(find(x(:,y)))), 1:size(x,2))
the output will be @(x)array(@(y)std(diff(find(x(:,y)))), 1:size(x,2)) not a number .. this is my main problem

Comment: yes that line creates an anonymous function, you still have to use the function. i.e. f(x). I'll change my example as it was confusing

Comment: I wrote exactly what you said, 
f = @(x)array(@(y)std(diff(find(x(:,y)))), 1:size(x,2));
f(data);
but it said "undefined function'array' for input arguments of type 'function_handle' ?

Comment: @User436823 Oy sorry another typo! It should be `arrayfun`

Comment: it works now but it gives NaN for most of the rows, do u know why? can I make it works foreach row alone?

Comment: @User436823 by rows I assume you mean columns?? You get NaN where the variance is undefined, i.e. fewer than 2 non-zero numbers in a column.

Comment: Sorry I mean columns :)

Comment: @User436823 Replace those NaN values with `isnan(..) = some_high_value`, as I think those columns represent good "spreadness" too. Take this as a suggestion, as I would leave it to you and Dan to make the final call.

Comment: I already added isnan and it is working fine now.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need an interval to find the "spreadness" locally, otherwise the `sample 1` (which is named as `Column 1` in the question) would appear as spread too between the 2nd and 3rd ones.

So, following that theory and assuming `input_array` to be the input array, you can try this approach -

```
intv = 10; %// Interval
diff_loc = diff(find(input_array))
spread_factor = sum(diff_loc(diff_loc<=intv)) %// desired output/score
```

For `sample 1`, `spread_factor` gives `4` and for `sample 2` it is `23`.

---

Another theory that you can employ would be if you assume an interval  such that distance between consecutive ones must be greater than or equal to that interval. This theory would lead us to a code like this -

```
intv = 3; %// Interval
diff_loc = diff(find(input_array))
spread_factor = sum(diff_loc>=intv)
```

With this new approach - For `sample 1`, `spread_factor` is `1` and for `sample 2` it is `5`.